# count of desktops only returns 1

Tags: applescript, desktop

Any idea why the following script would only return 1, when I clearly have more than one Desktop open?

```
tell application "System Events"
    set n to count of desktops
    display alert n
end tell
```

I have even tried it with JAX JavaScript and also get 1.

*Note: For reference I am using El Capitan (MBP Mid 2012)*

[image]

Comment: 'desktops' are 'monitors' not Spaces. there's no programmatic way to count Spaces, short of using the GUI, which is very hit & miss.

Comment: ok that explains it then. Disappointed with the lack of control over spaces...

Comment: Tell me about it ;-) If even fullscreen apps were included in the regular Space count… I think someone forgot about Spaces when they developed the 'new' fullscreen. Let's hope sense returns to that camp, maybe 10.12… ?

Comment: A late checkmark for accepted ;) but note 10.14 still isn't bringing any sanity to Spaces, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'desktops' are 'monitors' not Spaces.
There's no programmatic way to count Spaces, short of using the GUI, which is very hit & miss.